# git ignoring remote file

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have access to  a private remote repository on bitbucket and running git clone on it. The files seem to copy fine but package.json in the root of the repository is completely ignored, although I can see it fine in bitbucket.
How do I force getting all the files? Or maybe the repository owner should do something about it like checking it in - although I believe it was done if it's in the repository. The repository owner is claiming he tried to clone it to a new directory himself and it was fine.

Any help appreciated!

**UPD**
Here's what I get after entering the password:

```
remote: Counting objects: 8452, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (6266/6266), done.
remote: Total 8452 (delta 1410), reused 8303 (delta 1325)
Receiving objects: 100% (8452/8452), 40.11 MiB | 123 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1410/1410), done.
error: unable to create file node_modules/gulp-bower/node_modules/bower/node_mod
ules/update-notifier/node_modules/configstore/node_modules/js-yaml/node_modules/
argparse/node_modules/underscore.string/dist/underscore.string.min.js (No such f
ile or directory)
fatal: cannot create directory at 'node_modules/gulp-bower/node_modules/bower/no
de_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/configstore/node_modules/js-yaml/node_mo
dules/argparse/node_modules/underscore.string/test/test_underscore': No such fil
e or directory
```

Comment: ok, solved the problem by using git bash, however I'm wondering why the standard command prompt git would behave differently. I'm on windows and git version is 1.8.1.msysgit.1. Maybe someone can explain this. Thanks!

Comment: Can you give us more information about what happened when you cloned it with the standard command prompt git? Did it raise an error? Or did the file just not appear? There's no reason for any file to be ignored on a clone - unless the file only exists on a different branch of the repository, in which case you'd need to checkout the other branch in order to see it.

Comment: Note that Windows has a maximum file path length of 260. Some of the files that threw errors look like they're pushing that limit, depending on where you cloned them to.

Comment: Derek, thank you, that was the cause. I'm just wondering who and why would downvote the question - other people might have a similar issue. Anyway thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows has a maximum file path length of 260. Some of the files that threw errors look like they're pushing that limit, depending on where you cloned them to. Try making the file path shorter, or cloning the repository to a directory closer to the filesystem root (i.e. cloning to `C:\temp` instead of `C:\Users\dredfern\longdirectorynamehere\`).